# 2.90 - Spin tool with linked duplicates

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm using the spin tool to create a circular shape of objects (fig 1 as an example), however I can't find a way to link them.

[image]

When I edit the cube all the other cubes are left independent (fig 2). I'm trying to get the sort of behaviour you get when using an array, but have decided to use the spin tool instead as it's much easier to create a circle of objects.

[image]

I've tried using both Spin and Spin Duplicates but can't see a difference. And I've also tried the use duplicates option.

[image]

Any ideas on how to achieve my goal? or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: WIth the Spin tool you won't have instances, but what shape are you trying to achive exactly? If it's a series of cube, use the Array with Object Offset

Comment: It's a repeating shape that changes over time. I even tried using separation to create different instances of the object which worked great. However once you try to link the data all the cubes move to the exact same spot which defeated the purpose.

I think I'll have to use the array modifier however how do you create a circle like the above in a non destructive manner?

Answer (score 1):

The first method would be to use ***Array / Object Offset***:

- Create your cube, go in *Edit* mode, move it away from its origin:

[image]
[image]

- Create an empty at the exact same point as the cube origin:

[image]

- Give your cube an *Array* modifier, choose a *Count* of 12, deactivate *Relative Offset*, enable *Object Offset* and choose the empty as *Object*:

[image]

- Rotate the empty 30° on the Z axis, the cube instances rotate around:

[image]

- You can select the cube again and, in *Edit* mode, move/edit it. Use the *Array Merge* option if you want the instances to stick to each other.

[image]

The second method would be to use ***Instancing***:

- Create a 12 vertex circle, extrude inwards, give it *Instancing > Faces*:

[image]

- Create your cube, parent it to the circle, it will repeat circularly:

[image]